# How to wire input and output when creating flow for web socket?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-stream, akka-http

Assuming I have an actor `UserActor` that know how to work with incoming messages and how to send new ones, I want to handle web sockets inside Akka-Http, so I creating `Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed]`.

Here we getting new messages as JSON and sending them to `UserActor`. When source completed I receive `SourceDied` message:

```
    val incomingMessages: Sink[Message, NotUsed] =
      Flow[Message]
        .mapAsync(1) {
          case TextMessage.Strict(text)  => Future.successful(text)
          case TextMessage.Streamed(msg) => msg.runFold("")(_ + _)
        }
        .map(decode[IncomingMessage])
        .collect { case Right(msg) => msg }
        .map(_.toMessage)
        .to(Sink.actorRef[ChatMessage](userActor, SourceDied))
```

Here I register `out` for my `UserActor` at which It'll send messages:

```
    val outgoingMessages: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
      Source
        .actorRef[ChatMessage](20, OverflowStrategy.fail)
        .mapMaterializedValue { outActor =>
          userActor ! Connect(outActor)
          NotUsed
        }
        .map((x: ChatMessage) => OutgoingMessage.fromMessage(x))
        .map((outMsg: OutgoingMessage) => TextMessage(outMsg.asJson.toString))

    Flow.fromSinkAndSource(incomingMessages, outgoingMessages)
```

However, UserActor is one per user, and each user can have multiple sockets open simultaneously. So I just collecting `outs` to set inside `UserActor` and sending info to each of them. It works nice.

But when source sending me terminating message (`SourceDied` in my case), I don't know to which exactly `out` this `source` was assigned — and I can't decide which `out` I should inform about completion and then delete from my `outs` set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to change your `Flow` to take a unique identifier for each connection:

```
def websocketFlow(connectionId: String): Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] = {
  val incomingMessages: Sink[Message, NotUsed] =
    ...
    .to(Sink.actorRef[ChatMessage](userActor, SourceDied(connectionId)))

  val outgoingMessages: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
    Source
      .actorRef[ChatMessage](20, OverflowStrategy.fail)
      .mapMaterializedValue { outActor =>
        userActor ! Connect(connectionId, outActor)
        NotUsed
      }
      ...

  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(incomingMessages, outgoingMessages)
}
```

Obviously you would need to adjust the `SourceDied` and `Connect` messages to include a connection ID (which in this case could be generated with something like `java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString`, for example). Then in `UserActor`, replace the `Set` with a `Map`, the keys for which are the connection IDs. Using a `Map` will enable you to look up connection actors and remove them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

So, as I understood from @chunjef answer, there is no direct way to do so. And personally I decided not to use random ID generation, but to use one more Actor between socket and `UserActor`.

Basically, now I have `SocketHandlerActor(userActor: ActorRef)` to replace `UserActor` in socket creation part. It just connects to `UserActor` and sending all messages between socket and `UserActor`.

But when `SocketHandlerActor` receives `SourceDied` message, it just do stuff and then kills `out` and self with `PoisionPill`. `UserActor` removes it from own `outs` list, as soon as receives `Termination` message.